# Arduino Serial Communication can't read integers

Tags: arduino

I used the following code to read sequences of integers from Arduino (Arduino-Mega 2560) serial communication
but it gives me garbage (or wrong value), help  me to find out the bug please...

```
int time=0,i;
void setup() {
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  i=0;
  while(Serial.available()>0) {
    time=Serial.parseInt();
  }
  for(i=1;i<=time;i++){
    digitalWrite(6,1);
    delay(150);
    digitalWrite(6,0);
    delay(100);
  }
  time=0;
}
```

Comment: What data are you sending to the Arduino? What range of numbers?

Comment: all are integers ranges between 1-99

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. Or at least the logic is wrong.

Try this:

```
void loop(){
  if(Serial.available()) {
     time=Serial.parseInt();

     for(i=1;i<=time;i++){
        digitalWrite(6,1);
        delay(150);
        digitalWrite(6,0);
        delay(100);
     }
     time=0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it should work, but maybe the problem is in the data you are sending.

`Serial.parseInt()` expects ascii characters that represent a number. Are you sending a number encoded as a string of chars? Note that `Serial.write(99)` will send a single byte with value 99.

Since the numbers are in the range 0 to 99, they will fit in a single byte. Why not just send a byte and read the byte on the other end?

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  int time=0;
  if(Serial.available()>0) { // using while will read all the bytes and use the last one
    time = Serial.read();
  }
  for(int i=1; i<=time; i++){
    digitalWrite(6,1);
    delay(150);
    digitalWrite(6,0);
    delay(100);
  }
}
```